Uploading then showing image while Flask App is live
I'm creating a web application that allows a user to input coordinates for a plot, then see the resulting plot.
I have a function that creates this plot from the user input, I then save it to my 'static' folder, and then post this on the next html after hitting submit.
This works perfectly fine locally, but when I deploy my app is returns an Internal Server Error. It seems like it's an issue in writing to the static folder and then pulling from it while the app is live.
Plot function in Flask
@app.route("/plot", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def plot():
    form_data = request.form
    xcord = request.form.get('xcord')
    ycord = request.form.get('ycord')
    xcord = int(xcord)
    ycord = int(ycord)
    goal = Goal(xcord, ycord)
    percent = goal.is_goal()
    fig = goal.shot_chart()
    fig.savefig('static/myplot.png',  pad_inches=0, dpi=300)

    return render_template("plot.html", title = 'plot', fig = fig, form_data = form_data, xcord=xcord, ycord=ycord, percent=percent)

Plot.html
<h1>Shot Predictor</h1>
<h3>Enter the x and y coordinates of your shot and see the % chance of a goal!</h3>
<body>
    <p>
   <img src= "static/myplot.png" class = "soccer" height="504" width="864">
    <table class="center">
        <tr>
            <td>Percent chance of a goal: {{ percent }}</td>
        </tr> 
    </table>
   </p>
</body>

I tried changing file paths and also consulted other threads to no avail. I'm an amateur at web development.

Please qualify "doesn't work" ...

returns "Internal Server Error"

Set the DEBUG to True so you can see errors, It might be something to do with server permissions to create new files, also can you check if plots are being generated in static folder or not.
I would suggest you to try providing the full path in fig.savefig() like fig.savefig('/path/to/your/project/static/myplot.png',  pad_inches=0, dpi=300).

Thanks. I think it's a server permissions issue to create new file. I'm using GCP to deploy the app, any tips on where to change the server permissions?

@JoeSkvarna since you didn't clarify, have you tried what I asked you to do i.e. using absolute path instead of relative path. Here is a similar thread Flask permissions for file writing
